# send email by Mandrill

Tags: php, email, cakephp, mandrill

I need to send an email for mandrill. This Mandrill API implemented in my project, and send a test mail by apikey provided by the client. I have two options for sending mail, one is by my account of Mandrill and the other is that the user can login by MailChimp. Then insert the API KEY mandrill your account.

I have a default variable in conf file like this:

```
public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('noreply@example.com' => 'Example'),
    'host' => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'example@example.com',
    'password' => '12345678',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

To send mail through my account mandrill I do this:

```
$email = new FrameworkEmail();
$email->config('default');
$email->emailFormat('html');
```

And I give my account Mandrill data. But if the user chooses to identify with MailChimp and also add your API KEY Mandrill mails should be sent from your account transactional emails and not mine. Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible to authenticate with MailChimp and then send through Mandrill. The Mandrill API uses a different set of keys than the MailChimp API, so you won't have access to a user's Mandrill API keys if they're logged in through MailChimp.

**EDIT:** If you have a user's Mandrill API key, you should be able to feed it directly into the Mandrill send function from the [Mandrill SDK](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.php.html):

```
<?php 
$mandrill = new Mandrill('USER_PROVIDED_API_KEY_GOES_HERE');
$message = array(
    'html' => '<p>html content here</p>',
    // other details here
)
$async = False;
$ip_pool = null;
$send_at = null;

$result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
?>
```

More details on the Message function in the SDK can be found [here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html).

EDIT #2: Same approach can be achieved using CakeEmail - you just need to instantiate the `$email` class at the time that you receive the user's API key, rather than before.

CakeEmail recommends in a standard setup that you do this in your initial configuration:

```
class EmailConfig {
    public $mandrill = array(
        'transport' => 'Mandrill.Mandrill',
        'from' => 'from@example.com',
        'fromName' => 'FromName',
        'timeout' => 30,
        'api_key' => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        'emailFormat' => 'both',
    );
}
```

But we can't set this up with default values and then change it per user, using their API key. We need to instantiate this at the time that we receive the user's email, like so:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

// PHP code that takes in user email
$user_api_key = // this would come from a form, or from a user's record in the database

$email = new CakeEmail(array(
    'transport' => 'Mandrill.Mandrill',
    'from' => 'from@example.com',
    'fromName' => 'FromName',
    'timeout' => 30,
    'api_key' => $user_api_key,
    'emailFormat' => 'both',
));

// add CakeEmail details like $email->template, $email->subject(), etc.

$email->send();
```

So the principles are the same regardless of what framework is used. Rather than instantiating Mandrill configuration details in a global setting (like most email frameworks recommend), you will need to instantiate them at the time the user wants to send an email, using user-specific details.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm understanding better. But I have another problem, Mandrill not as plugin in my project this as a Vendor, only imports the classes then try to send mail with your code I get the error that the plugin is not installed on my project.

Comment: @hateful Sounds like the Mandrill CakePHP plugin just needs to be installed. This [link here](https://github.com/a2design-inc/Mandrill-CakePHP-plugin#installation) provides installation instructions, whether you prefer to `git clone` the plugin directly into your repository or use Composer to manage dependencies.

Comment: Thanks !, unfortunately I can not install mandrill in my project. Each client I make a copy of my project, I have around 40 and continue to add, so you should install on each Mandrill, so I wanted to do it alone regardless of the class. Not if I explain, nor if it will be possible, but your answer was about to serve, and I had hopeful :(